# Journey Builder Decision Split Rejecting everyone

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have an interaction where the decision split is routing all subscribers on the "remainder" path, even though they meet the criteria for the other path (which happens to be identical to the entry event which they just passed through.)

Any ideas why a decision activity would act this way? I am using Contact Data to build the filter (using various DEs that I've confirmed the subscribers exist in.) Thank you.

Comment: Is the Interaction running in Test mode?

Comment: I don't believe so! How do I know? I've activated the interaction and ran a fire event to inject users in to the journey.

Comment: If you've activated the Interaction, then it won't be in test mode. Have you set a 1:1 cardinal relationship from the Contact Record to the Attribute Set that you are using in your Decision Split Activity?

Comment: If you can provide a screenshot of your Attribute Group and Decision Split Activity rule that would help.

Comment: Ah! You sent me down the right path. I am using the same DE object under two different Attribute Groups (for testing and prod) and the root relationship is on the production DE object. I will need to make a copy of the DE for testing purposes.

Comment: Hmmm, yes that would be a problem.